# CollectionView binding data doesn't update after OnPropertyChanged is triggered

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a CollectionView with a binding to `ObservableCollection<Announce> Announces`  that is filled correctly with data when the page appears. Then I send a Post request creating a new Announce, the `OnPropertyChanged` method is called, data in `Announces` aswell as in `announces` is updated but the getter isn't called and data in the CollectionView isn't updated. Should the getter be called automatically after `OnPropertyChanged`? What am I missing in my code that doesn't update the UI?

The AnnouncesService is a simple service that returns ObservableCollections of Announce from http requests.
Here's my AnnouncesViewModel:

```
 public class AnnouncesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<Announce> announces;
        public ObservableCollection<Announce> Announces 
        {
            get => announces;
            set { announces = value; OnPropertyChanged("Announces"); } 
        }
        public AnnouncesService service;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public AnnouncesViewModel()
        {
            service = new AnnouncesService();
            Announces = new ObservableCollection<Announce>();
            getAnnounces();
        }

        public async Task addAnnounce(Announce announce)
        {
            Announces = await service.PostAnnounceAsync(announce); //same as using getAnnounces again            
        }
       
        public async void getAnnounces()
        {
            Announces = await service.GetAnnouncesAsync();            
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

Here's my XAML with binding

```
 <ContentPage Title="">
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
                <vm:AnnouncesViewModel/>
            </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ContentPage.Content>

            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Announces}"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding location}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

and a TabbedPage that calls AddAnnounce from the `AnnouncesViewModel`

```
 public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
    {
        private AnnouncesService service;
        private AnnouncesViewModel viewModel;
        public TabbedPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            service = new AnnouncesService();
            viewModel = new AnnouncesViewModel();
        }

        private async void AddAnnounce(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Announce announce = new Announce(localtion_entry.Text,sport_entry.Text,1);
            await viewModel.addAnnounce(announce);
        }
}
```

Comment: why aren't you just adding the new data to the ObservableCollection, instead of creating a new instance of the ObservableCollection every time?

Comment: @Jason If you mean in the ViewModel in addAnnounce, when I try `Announces.Add(await service.PostAnnounceAsync(announce));` (with the service returning a simple announce) , `OnPropertyChanged` isn't called, but the getter is, so it's still doesn't work.

Comment: an ObservableCollection raises a CollectionChanged event when an item is added or removed - that's the entire purpose of using it instead of a List

Comment: @Jason Should this answer my question? Adding to the list doesn't update the UI data either.

Comment: only create and assign the OC once.  I believe that you are breaking the binding by repeatedly assigning it.

Comment: What is the relation between the XAML you showed and `TabbedPage1` ?

Comment: @Jason So now I create the OC<Announce> in my constructor and use Add method to update it's content but the UI still doesn't update. The getter is called before the Announce is added to the OC and OnPropertyChanged doesn't fire.

Comment: Your two pages appear to each have their own instance of the VM.

Comment: @Jasonthe the XAML is the content of one Page in TabbedPage1, so there is only one instance of VM in the cs code.

Comment: As @Jason pointed-out you are probably using 2 different instances of your `AnnouncesViewModel` one created in the xaml, bound to the ui but data are not updated in it , and the other created in code where data are updated but not the one bound to the ui.

Comment: So if I remove binding from my XAML code and put it in cs instead it should fix the problem by removing one instance, right?

Comment: We don't know how your pages and TabbedPage are made, but yeah if you assign the `BindingContext` of your `ContentPage` in the code-behind the same instance of your `AnnouncesViewModel ` that you are working on in your code it should work.

Comment: @Cfun it worked! Huge thanks to you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was I was using 2 different instances of AnnouncesViewModel. One in XAML and one in cs code to call `AddAnnounce`.
To fix this I removed this part from my XAML code

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
                <vm:AnnouncesViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

added `x:Name = "page"` to my ContentPage and assigned the BindingContext in TabbedPage1 constructor:

```
private AnnouncesViewModel viewModel;
public TabbedPage1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    viewModel = new AnnouncesViewModel();
    page.BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

I also use Add method in AnnouncesViewModel to add content to my Announces ObservableCollection.